# call jsp:useBean from javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jsp, jquery, servlets

I want to get person object in servlet. But I don't want to submit the form.

This is the jsp.

```
<form>
name: <input type="text" name="name" >
<input type="button" value="Submit" >
</form>
<jsp:useBean id="person" type="com.aop.bean.Person" class="com.aop.bean.Person" >
<jsp:setProperty name="person" property="*" />
</jsp:useBean>
```

My bean class :: Person.java

```
public class Person {

private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

I want the object of person in the servlet without submitting the form. I want to pass that jsp:useBean object by JavaScript or jQuery Ajax.
Is that possible to call jsp:useBean by Javascript or JQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You can get it through el tags for example in js code if it is in same jsp you can make an ajax call like this -

```
$.ajax({
   url:'/someURL',
   data:'name=${person.name}'
})
```

so in the parameter you will get the name of the user

Explanation - 
${person.name} will return you the name of the person.

Comment: If I do data:'name=${person.name}' then I did not get any value in servlet because "${person.name}" this is nothing but a string.

Comment: Yes name ${person.name} is a string value and you will get name if you have set it correct. That was an example if you want to send the whole user object you can create a json object by getting all the value of user in similar way - data:'{"name"="${person.name"}}' and add all the other properties in similar way

Comment: Thanx for your help. May be I was wrong. I think the property name is not setting in the person object, that's why I'm getting null value.

Comment: Yeah that could be one reason to be sure try printing the value on jsp to see what value it does have.

Comment: Yes I'm not getting the value. I've tried like this.
<c:out value="${person.name}"></c:out>

Comment: You are using jsp:setProperty like - <jsp:setProperty name="person" property="*" />

It says you are setting all the properties of person bean from the request. for the same you must have all the values of person bean in request parameter. refer the following example it might help

http://www.javatpoint.com/jsp-setProperty-and-jsp-getProperty-action-tag

Comment: I've posted in details. Can you please see that?
Thnaks in advance.

Comment: <jsp:setProperty property="*" name="person" /> this tag will assign the values of all the property of person object if value is there in the request parameter with same name as object attribute so at the time of landing to the page there is no value in the request so when you are getting the value through ${person.name} its null. - continued

Comment: In second scenario you are getting value not because of ${person.name} but in the form there is an input field with name attribute so you are getting its value in request attribute. So to get the value in ajax you have to take value with jquery only like this -
data: $('input[name=name]').val();